# how to know key in multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an array :

```
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1418
            [item_qty] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_syskey] => 2013010103330149001
            [item_qty] => 1
        )

)
```

I am running a foreach loop as

```
foreach($array as $val){

}
```

How can I know that the next **key** is item_syskey or item_id ?

Actually I am changing array according to item_id and item_syskey .That means in loop if key is equal to item_id then will do something and if item_syskey then o something.

Comment: Check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) or isset to check a key:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
  if (isset($array[$key + 1]) && isset($array[$key + 1]['item_id'])) {
    // next item has item id
  }
}
```

But you sould try to avoid having different types in your arrays.

Comment: actually the problem is I already have many lines of code with foreach($array as $val) so if I changes it to foreach($array as $key=>$val) then I have to update the code at many places so Please give me answer based in above.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    // Check value of $key here
}
```

Comment: actually the problem is I already have many lines of code with 
foreach($array as $val) so if I changes it to foreach($array as $key=>$val) then I have to update the code at many places so Please give me answer based in above.

Comment: @Shreya If you are doing the same code in many places, maybe that code should be put centrally in a function?

Comment: No it's not same code my mean was that using the format of array (which I written in question) at so many places e.g I am using $val['item_id'] etc..

Comment: @Shreya Wait what? You _need_ the key. Ergo, you want to do something with the key there, which requires writing code. So, you are effectively saying: no, that's 1 line to high in the code for me, I choose not to use this, I want to write 1 line lower?

Comment: @Wrikken I just want to change the values of **item_qty** which is based on item_id and item_syskey e.g if it is item_id the change it's item_qty to 2 if it is item_syskey then change to 3

Comment: @Shreya so you want to write some code which changes depending on the key, but you won't change the line above which allows you to actually get the key in the first place.

Comment: You'll _have_ to alter your foreach loop (mind you, you don't need the key if you loop by reference by `foreach($array as &$val)`, but I suppose it's the same problem with the mystical 'then _all_ my foreach loops need to change', which makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I'd mod troll if it was possible.

Comment: @Wrikken I am not getting. Please give me code how to solve it